# How assign char * value to char using C

Tags: c

I have variable `char * amount;` and `char t_amount;`
I want to assign amount to t_amount.

```
char * amount = "sdf";
char t_amount = amount;
printf("%s t_amount \n", t_amount);
// I am expecting : sdf t_amount
```

when i print, segmentation error occurs so how do i fix this?
Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Why do you want to use `t_amount` and not just use `amount` (or another `char*`) directly?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your code makes no sense

Comment: `char t_amount[MAX_LENGTH+1];  strcpy(t_amount, amount);`

Answer (score 0):

the variable `amount` is a pointer so when `char t_amount = amount;`you are actually assigning the pointer's address to your `t_amount` variable, hence the segfault

If `t_amount` was a `char *` you could have done that assignment without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
char * amount = "sdf";
char t_amount = amount;
printf("%s t_amount \n", t_amount);

amount is a pointer you can not assign that kind of address to a variable. its an error.
when you declare char t_amount = amount, you assign a string to a char because an address is a string.
```